# Convert timestamp from GPS

Tags: datetime, xamarin, gps

I'm getting a GPS position in a xamarin app. The timestamp provided from the GPS position is formatted like this: 13-05-2019.

I then make it a string "13-05-2019" and sending it to the .net core backend. The backend makes it 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000, because it expects a U.S. date, which is fine.

I know I can use Culture for setting the conversion, but the app is gonna be used in many different countries, so I can't just hardcode the Culture country.

So how is it done the right way? Do you lookup the country from the position and then convert it to the right Culture by having some sort of method for that, or do can you get the format from DateTime and send it with - or a third option?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what problem you are trying to solve, but in general when dealing with an app that will be used globally you want to use UTC times, which are not tied to a specific time zone.  The C# DateTime class has support for this

Comment: Does utc always give me the same format, or does it change for the users language, like 13-05-2019 and other phones would be 05-13-2019 ?

Comment: UTC is an internal storage format.  You can output it in any local TZ or format you want

Comment: You can custom the time format, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) document would help.